# How many ways are there to sit $n$ couples on a bench when every couple sits together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to sit $n$ couples on a bench with $2n$ sits, when every couple sits together?

How many ways are there to sit the couples so that none of the couples will sit together?

Comment: For the first question I answered $(n*2!)*n!$ for $n$ = couples, $2!$ = sort inside the couples, n! = sort of couples on the bench.

Comment: For the first question, you can sort inside the couples independently, so it should be $(2!)^nn!$

Comment: Pardon me, could you please explain why $2^n$?

Comment: @Georgey We sort _each_ one of the pairs, 2 options for the first pair, 2 options for the second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints.*

1. First count the number of ways to seat just the couples, as if they were one person.  Then count the number of ways to arrange the individuals within each couple.
2. Apply the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: I can't understand why the *individuals within each couple* is $(2!)^n$ and not $(n*2!)n!$

Comment: @Eran Each couple may be seated with person $A$ to the left of person $B$ or vice versa.  That's two possibilities, one for each couple, thus $2^n$.

Comment: Should I solve 2. by applying the principle and using a $\sum$ that it's index runs on the number of couples that are not seated together? Something like $\sum(-1)^i$${n}\choose{i}$$(n-i)!$
I know that I might have written pure BS but I'm trying not to.

Comment: @Eran You could do that, you may have to subtract it from $(2n)!$ at the end in that case

Comment: After lots of thoughts, is this answer correct? $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{{(-1)^i}\cdot{(2!)^{n-i}}\cdot{(n-i)!}}$ If not, what am I missing?